# Backbone.js and javascript undefined values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js

I am practicing with Backbone.js but i think i have a basic JavaScript problem.I am getting additional undefined values while iterating the loop end fetching the input value.If i do myarr.push(kids[i].value) and alert it when it is finished i get some additional commas.It is like next array item has commas on both sides plus comma from previous item.I think i am missing on some js basics but i don't know what is the problem so i can go back and learn it.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function funk() {
      var myarr = new Array();
      var kids = document.getElementById("mydiv").children;

      for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        document.write(kids[i].value + "<br>");
      }    
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" id="add">Add some</button>
  <button type="button" id="rem">Remove</button>

  <script>    
    var MyView =vBackbone.View.extend({
      tagName:'div',
      id:'mydiv',

      render: function() {
        this.$el.html("<input type='text' class='clickable' /><br>");
        return this;
      }   
    });

    var v = new MyView();
    $('body').append(v.render().el);

    $("#add").click(function() {
      $("#mydiv").append("<input type='text' class='clickable2' /><br>");
    });

    $("#rem").click(function() {
      $(".clickable2:last-of-type").remove();
    });
  </script>
  <button type="button" onclick="funk()">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might help to ask a question—what you're trying to do is unclear. Also, please provide an example of the data you are storing in your array.

Comment: @AlienBishop I am trying to get the value of all input fields and let's say use them for validation.If i do myarr.push(kids[i].value) i get value1,,value2,,value3,  notice the additional commas.Where do they come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you're assuming all the children of the mydiv element are one of your inputs... when that's patently not so.

When rendered, your mydiv looks like this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <input type='text' class='clickable' /><br>
</div>
```

And if you click a couple times you get this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <input type='text' class='clickable' /><br>
   <input type='text' class='clickable' /><br>
   <input type='text' class='clickable' /><br>
</div>
```

Note that there are SIX children of the #mydiv element (yes, the br tags count).
Your funk() method then iterates these children, and adds the .value() method of each to the array.  The br tags' .value() call returns nothing, so that's why you've got "empty" values in your array output.

If you just want the input's in your array, then use this selector rather than getting the #mydiv's children:

```
$("#mydiv > input")
```

That will give you an array of input elements, all of which are direct descendants of the #mydiv element.  Do with that array what you will.